# Fonts used in this book and change thickness of lmodern

Tags: fonts

The fonts specified in this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1466583282) are really interesting for people writing a thesis. I was wondering if any of you can give me some more information on what are the fonts they use? Specifically on pages 6 and 7. Please find attached screenshots.

What is the font used to write section 1.4 and the text itself? 
My guess is that the text is written in `times`.
Section 1.4.1 is written using `\textsf`

What was used for Figure 1.3?

Here is page 7:[image]
Here is page 6: [image]

I would like to use these fonts for my thesis.

After the comment from @egreg, you can ignore this comment. This text seems to show Palatino. 
For instance, the font in this [text](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/robertson/robertson.pdf), is much thicker that it is in my [thesis](http://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template) (after adding \usepackage{lmodern}, and removing times form the document class). I do not know where to begin to make it thicker

Comment: there are no copyright issues for the print of the words as they don't constitute the content. So please take a screenshot

Comment: Uploaded the pictures as per your suggestion..@percusse

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges: the font used in the article on PracTeX is Palatino, your thesis seems to use Times. Neither is the same as in the book.

Comment: I'm trying to get LatinModern with lmr12 running, and I seem to be failing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took a look at the ebook from my library, and the typefaces used in the PDF, according to the properties, are all of the [Latin Modern](https://ctan.org/pkg/lm) family.

[image]

Comment: The main text doesn't look like Latin modern. Question of curiosity: does the font family change based on the class? And the Latin modern consists of 72 fonts, I'm having a hard time pin pointing which one it is.

Comment: Most of them consist  in `optical sizes`. It's not up to you to choose if you use `lmr12` or `lmr8` for instance, it's the format.

Comment: I added a picture of what fonts the PDF says it contains

Comment: How do enable any of the given fonts... i used `\usepackage{lmodern}` and how do we set the mainfont?